# docx4j 3.0 pdf export failing with Docx4JException

Tags: java, xslt, pdf, docx4j

I'm trying to use docx4j 3.0 to load an existing docx file, make a few simple textual changes and save as PDF.  My code looks like this:

```
        WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load (new File (template));
        MainDocumentPart doc = wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart ();

        try
        {
            VariablePrepare.prepare (wordMLPackage);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Warning: VariablePrepare failed: " + e);
        }

                    (here I enumerate all Text nodes and make changes as required)

        PdfConversion c = new Conversion (wordMLPackage);
        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream (outputFile)) {
            c.output (out, new PdfSettings ());
        }
```

This is producing the following exception:

```
org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception exporting package
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:79)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toFO(Docx4J.java:467)
    at org.docx4j.Docx4J.toPDF(Docx4J.java:477)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion.output(Conversion.java:70)
    at net.meridiandigital.binco.invoicegen.InvoiceGenerator.generateFile(InvoiceGenerator.java:80)
    at net.meridiandigital.binco.invoicegen.Test.main(Test.java:46)
Caused by: org.docx4j.openpackaging.exceptions.Docx4JException: Exception loading default template "org/docx4j/convert/out/fo/docx2fo.xslt", Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.common.XsltCommonFunctions.notImplemented(reference, node-type, string)'
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.loadDefaultTemplates(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:92)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.getDefaultTemplate(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:75)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.getTemplates(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:66)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.process(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:57)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.process(AbstractWmlExporter.java:63)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractWmlExporter.process(AbstractWmlExporter.java:32)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractExporter.export(AbstractExporter.java:71)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Cannot convert argument/return type in call to method 'org.docx4j.convert.out.common.XsltCommonFunctions.notImplemented(reference, node-type, string)'
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:945)
    at org.docx4j.XmlUtils.getTransformerTemplate(XmlUtils.java:842)
    at org.docx4j.convert.out.common.AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.loadDefaultTemplates(AbstractXsltExporterDelegate.java:88)
    ... 11 more
```

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't be using

`com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`

but rather

`org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl`

(You need the real Xalan on your classpath)

See also instantiateTransformerFactory() at line 224 of https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/XmlUtils.java

Comment: Thanks.  It's rather unfortunate that the logging system you're using decides not to display helpful messages like the one you've included there by default (my personal preference would be a system that displays all messages unless configured otherwise) and that as I haven't figured out how to configure logging yet, I missed it. :(

Comment: Interestingly, though, I did have xalan-2.7.1.jar on my classpath... but it has a transitive dependency on 'serializer-2.7.1.jar' which I had somehow missed.

Comment: (and, yes, I know I *really* should be using maven...)

Comment: In fairness, `log.error("Warning: Xalan jar missing from classpath; xslt not supported",e);` is pretty clear!